# How do I make a search function for my Next.js web app that uses Supabase

Tags: next.js, supabase

So, I have a database of people. I want to have a search functionality for the database in the web app.

I tried using the Full Text Search functionality described here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/full-text-search

But it only works for entire words when I want it to work letter by letter. For example, I am using the last name of the people as my column that I want to search. If the list of last names is `['Adams', 'Charles', 'Brown']` when I type `C`, it should return `['Charles']`.

Thank you for any help you can contribute!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iLike()](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/ilike) filter.

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('people')
  .select()
  .ilike('name', '%Ch%') // Will return any people where `name` contains `Ch` such as Charles
```